# Display data after subscribe from firebase snapshot

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs

I'm struggling with rxjs.. I would like to sort an array coming from my subscription.
But the sort never play.. 
SO first I tried to display userBirthdayDate from service but didn't work like expected.

this is my service

```
 getAllUsers() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      firebase
        .database()
        .ref()
        .child('users')
        .on(
          'value',
          snapshot => {
            resolve(
              snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
                this.usersBirthday = childSnapshot.val()
                  ? childSnapshot.val()
                  : [];
                this.emitBirthday();
              })
            );
          },
          error => {
            reject(error);
          }
        );
    });
  }
```

my component.ts

```
export class WidgetBirthdayComponent implements OnInit {
  users: User[];
  usersBirthdayDate = [];
  usersSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private userService: UsersService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // this.usersSubscription = this.userService.birthdaySubject.subscribe(
    //   test => {
    //     this.usersBirthdayDate.push(test);
    //   }
    // );
    // this.userService.emitBirthday();
    // this.userService.getAllUsers();

    const myArray = [
      {
        name: "Joel",
        birthdayDate: "Wednesday, November 25, 1992"
      },
      {
        name: "Sarah",
        birthdayDate: "Thursday, April 16, 1992"
      },
      {
        name: "Beverly",
        birthdayDate: "Thursday, February 26, 1998"
      }
    ];

    myArray.sort(function compare(a, b) {
      const now = new Date();
      const dateA = new Date(a.birthdayDate);
      dateA.setFullYear(now.getFullYear());
      if (dateA.getTime() - now.getTime() < 0) {
        dateA.setFullYear(now.getFullYear() + 1);
      }
      const dateB = new Date(b.birthdayDate);
      dateA.setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear());
      dateA.setFullYear(now.getFullYear());
      if (dateB.getTime() - now.getTime() < 0) {
        dateB.setFullYear(now.getFullYear() + 1);
      }
      return dateA.getTime() - dateB.getTime();
    });
    console.log(myArray);
  }
```

So I tried with strong data and my function sort is working well.. but I can"t use usersBirthdayDate[] on it.. PLease need help :)

Answer (score 1):

In case you tried to sort the array outside the subscription (like in your snippet of code), it is not working because, when your code runs, you only sort the array once in the ngOnInit hook. By then, your observable hasn't emitted any userBirthday yet. So the `usersBirthdayDate` array is empty.

I'm not sure where/when you are trying to make you sort happen but have you tried something like the following:

```
this.usersSubscription = this.userService.birthdaySubject.subscribe(
    test => {
        this.usersBirthdayDate.push(test);
        this.usersBirthdayDate.sort(yourSortingFunction);
    }
);
```

If that does not work maybe you could explain a bit more what happens in your subscription when you receive a new user? Then I'll be able to edit my answer if needed.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I tried also this before.. but still didn't work as except.. I'll develop more under !!

Comment: Just an additional comment/question; in your new answer, the console log you show has Sarah before Thomas, so some kind of sorting occurred right? I would need to see a bit more code from your service or component..is it possible that you change the `usersBirthdayDate` array somewhere else? Maybe pushing the Sophie element after you sorted the array with only 2 elements?

Comment: I pushed my service.ts last com thanks anyway for your help

Comment: I think my function sort doesn't work properly cause if I change 1992 to 1998 since 1992 is before :p  I will always get Sophie at the end

Answer (score 0):

So this is my component.ts

I'm getting this on my console :

```
an array with the three elements inside my database 

1: {birthdayDate: "Thursday, April 16, 1992", firstName: "Sarah", lastName: "Doe", photoUrl: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/dashbo…=media&token=9a2ee641-e5ee-4be5-827c-8369903a04ec"}
2: {birthdayDate: "Wednesday, November 25, 1992", firstName: "Thomas", lastName: "Loe", photoUrl: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/dashbo…=media&token=6736f24b-7c60-4722-9fad-9a8e73cc0e0a"}
3: {birthdayDate: "Thursday, February 26, 1998", firstName: "Sophie", lastName: "test", photoUrl: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/dashbo…=media&token=8ff30a9d-c644-4df6-8ecb-243121ccd7de"}
    length: 4
```

but the function sort still doesn't work cause I have to get same array with Sophie first and sarah and Thomas. And when I tried with same data direct in component, the function is working well..

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UsersService } from '../../services/users.service';
import { User } from '../../models/user';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-widget-birthday',
  templateUrl: './widget-birthday.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./widget-birthday.component.scss']
})
export class WidgetBirthdayComponent implements OnInit {
  users: User[];
  usersBirthdayDate = [];
  usersSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private userService: UsersService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.usersSubscription = this.userService.birthdaySubject.subscribe(
      test => {
        this.usersBirthdayDate.push(test);
        this.usersBirthdayDate.sort(function compare(a, b) {
          const now = new Date();
          const dateA = new Date(a.birthdayDate);

          dateA.setFullYear(now.getFullYear());
          if (dateA.getTime() - now.getTime() < 0) {
            dateA.setFullYear(now.getFullYear() + 1);
          }
          const dateB = new Date(b.birthdayDate);
          dateA.setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear());
          dateA.setFullYear(now.getFullYear());
          if (dateB.getTime() - now.getTime() < 0) {
            dateB.setFullYear(now.getFullYear() + 1);
          }
          return dateA.getTime() - dateB.getTime();
        });
        console.log(this.usersBirthdayDate);
      }
    );
    this.userService.emitBirthday();
    this.userService.getAllUsers();

    // const myArray = [
    //   {
    //     name: 'Thomas',
    //     birthdayDate: 'Wednesday, November 25, 1992'
    //   },
    //   {
    //     name: 'Sarah',
    //     birthdayDate: 'Thursday, April 16, 1992'
    //   },
    //   {
    //     name: 'Sophie',
    //     birthdayDate: 'Thursday, February 26, 1998'
    //   }
    // ];
  }
}
```

service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { User } from '../models/user';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UsersService {
  users: User[] = [];
  usersSubject = new Subject<User[]>();
  birthdaySubject = new Subject<User[]>();
  usersBirthday: User[] = [];

  constructor() {}

  emitUsers() {
    this.usersSubject.next(this.users);
  }

  emitBirthday() {
    this.birthdaySubject.next(this.usersBirthday);
  }



  getAllUsers() {
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref()
      .child('users')
      .on('value', snapshot => {
        this.usersBirthday = snapshot.val()
          ? snapshot.val()
          : console.log('oro');
        this.emitBirthday();
      });
  }
}
```